# Where does the verb "farti" come from?

Tags: etymology

As far as I know, the words' roots in Esperanto come from non-constructed languages ([this is what Wikipedia says about it](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto#Living_language)).

As I speak English, Russian and some French and know a bit of Latin, I very often can guess the meaning of words because they resemble their English/Russian/French/Latin equivalents (or at least relatives).

The problem is with the verb *farti* (*to be* / *to feel*), especially in sentences like *Kiel vi fartas?* (*How are you doing?* / *How do you do?*). Mi pardonpetas, but I can't sorta unhook 'farti' in Esperanto from 'to fart' in English.

As for the similarities in other languages I know, the only one can be found in French, but it's not so similar, to my mind:

> *faire* (fr., *to do*) <-> *farti* (esp.)

I'm constantly thinking of the wrong translation when encountering 'farti' in texts, so the questions are: *where does 'farti' come from?*

Comment: I always thought maybe it comes from the same root as “to fare” in English. So “kiel vi fartas” could be thought of as being like “how do you fare”. I don't have any references to back this up though so it's just speculation.

Comment: There is `edz` which seems an invented term, but the German `(Wohl)fahrt` could be the source somehow (gaan [nl], gehen/Fahrt [de] all express "go").

Answer (score 18):

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/farti#Etymology) seems to confirm my suspicion that *farti* is derived from German *fahren* or English *fare*. More likely the former, as German *fahren* does include the *t* in some of its forms.

Answer (score 10):

In the dictionary Konciza Etimologia Vortaro by André Cherpillod is:

> **farti.** G Wohl*fahrt* «bonfarto, bonstato» ← Fahrt «veturado» ← HE por «trairi».
>
> **fari.** I fare, Oc far, F faire ← L făcĕre ← HE dhe, dha «meti». (...)

The abbreviations are G: *germana* (German), HE: *hindeŭropa* (Indo-European), I: *itala* (Italian), Oc: *okcitana* (Occitan), F: *franca* (French), L: *latina* (Latin).

Note that "to be" is not a good translation for *"farti"*. The dictionary of [Lernu](http://lernu.net) translates *farti* as "to fare, to be doing, to feel". In the [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#farti) is *"Esti en tia aŭ alia sanstato"*.

The German word *Wohlfahrt* is in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/farti#Etymology) too, as shown by [Hans Adler](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/16/where-does-the-verb-farti-come-from/50#50). The same origins of the word *fari* are pointed by [Luke Marlin](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/16/where-does-the-verb-farti-come-from/45#45).

Answer (score 3):

French speaker here, `faire` is not the translation of `farti` but of `fari`.

For `farti`, see the answer of [Hans Adler](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/16/where-does-the-verb-farti-come-from/50#50)

---

For the sake of completeness, I'll leave here the part of my old answer about the root of `fari`.

*A quick lookup on Wiktionary for `faire` shows that the root is the latin [facere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire), which means ["(the action of) doing, making, creating"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/facere#Latin).
It therefore seems to me that `facere` might be a suitable root for `fari`.*

Comment: I think the French word "faire" is more closely related to the Esperanto word "fari" which in English both translate as "to do/ to make"

Comment: @KyleBailey I don't know `fari`, but what I can add is that in French, `how are you doing` cannot be translated with the verb `faire` which almost exclusively the act of doing

Comment: Yes, fari and farti are different. "Kiel vi fartas?" Is used like "Comment allez vous?"

Comment: I knew `farti`, but didn't know `fari`. After looking up the exact definitions, it seems I was wrong, I left some information about the mistake, not sure if useful.

Comment: No problem. It's difficult to explain something about three different languages on an online forum. No doubt many have confused fari and farti!

Comment: I am pretty sure the closest to Esperanto *fari* is Italian *fare*. They mean the same and the roots are phonetically identical.

Comment: @nerimarkinde French `faire` and italtian `fare` both come from latin `facere`. And I was not implying French was the root, I just looked from there because OP explicitly mentionned it.